# What does the Forms3 Version Number in Visual Basic 6.0 mean?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have an old Visual Basic 6.0 Installation.
In the information window (? -> About MS VB...) the Version Number is shown:

```
Version 9782
VBA: Retail 6.0.9782
Forms3: 12.0.6604.100
```

Now my questions:

What does Forms3 mean? 
And where can I find updates for it (does updates exist?)?

Many thanks in advance!
Daniel

Comment: That's not VB6, VBA is typically used in Office apps.  Forms3 is an ActiveX component that [supports UserForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853685/how-to-create-an-user-interface-userform-in-excel-vba), used to add custom UI to an Office program.  It is very old and hasn't been updated in very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF: [Chapter 2 Visual Basic 6 and Visual Basic .NET: Differences](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/C/8/CC8C1F44-D96F-4E74-8C8A-0734D958610C/Chapter2.pdf)

> The forms package found in Visual Basic 6 is local to that environment.
>   You can use Visual Basic 6 forms only in Visual Basic 6. Microsoft has tried in
>   the past to create a single, standard forms package that could be shared across
>   multiple products such as Visual Basic, C++, and Office. The initiative, called
>   Forms3 (pronounced Forms Cubed), never realized this goal. Forms3 is alive
>   and well in Office but was never made fully compatible with the Visual Basic
>   forms package.

This *is* VB6:

```
Version 9782
VBA: Retail 6.0.9782
Forms3: 12.0.6604.100
```

But the 12.0 Forms3 is from Office 2003.  VB6 is tightly bound to Office in many regards and can even use the FM20 Forms Designer if you enable it.  This gives you the option to "Add Microsoft Forms 2.0 Form" as well as native VB forms, primarily for creating Office add-in DLLs.